# Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I am getting the following error while running my rails app in Ubuntu server

> FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes. Visit
>   https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers
>   for info on how to fix this.

I have followed the above GitHub page, but I was unable to write in max_user_watches which were set in 8192 and I want to set that to 524288.
in `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` the file was in only read mode.I tried to grant write permissions, but I was getting permission denied error even with root access.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Sometimes this can happen if too many processes trying to access the same folder as of your rails project. For ex. I was accessing the rails project folder on 2 IDEs Sublime, VS Code also had a few process working on the same folder. So while starting the server I faced the same error. If you don't want to increase watchers limit, just turn off any one process accessing that folder. It should work.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

1000 is way too small, try with 524288 as explained in the wiki page: [https://github.com/guard/listen/blob/master/README.md#increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)

> Listen uses inotify by default on Linux to monitor directories for
> changes. It's not uncommon to encounter a system limit on the number
> of files you can monitor. For example, Ubuntu Lucid's (64bit) inotify
> limit is set to 8192.

and

> If you are running Debian, RedHat, or another similar Linux
> distribution, run the following in a terminal:
>
> ```
> echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
> ```
>
> If you are running ArchLinux, run the following command instead
>
> ```
> echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/40-max-user-watches.conf && sudo sysctl --system
> ```

Comment: however, i was able to get it to work on arch with `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`

Comment: FYI - the link to the github page above is now broken

Answer (score 32):

Just try to execute this from your console

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Hope this will work for you .

References: [click here](https://prashantrorblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/28/fatal-listen-error-unable-to-monitor-directories-for-changes/)

Answer (score 7):

For others who may have this issue. I had a VM disconnect which left the previous rails server running. Running below resolved the issue without needing to up the number of watcher.

```
 kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I just need to turn off the terminal and then start it back again. It works when I try to run `rails c` command :)

Comment: The classic "reboot and retry" method.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting Gemfile.lock and running 'bundle' in the project directory terminal worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me as I had a number of ruby processes currently running that I was unaware of. Just need to terminate them and all is good

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue during development while running `rake` (even with `rake -h`), and the solution from https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers did not work, neither did killing the running ruby processes, killing the terminal or even restarting the computer.

To avoid this error I did a new and clean clone of my project and then `rake` was working (maybe `git clean -fdx` could have worked but I did not try it).

I was running rake version 13.0.3, rails 6.1.1, ruby 2.7.2p137.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @mayur-shah's answer,

It worked for me after closing the server and console. So, if you are running rails server/console, close that first.