# How else to fix "Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, inotify

I get the following error when I try to run `rails c production` on my server.

```
FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes.
Visit https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers for info on how to fix this.
```

I'm able to fix it with the accepted solution here: [Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225677/listen-error-unable-to-monitor-directories-for-changes)

However, I'm wondering why this happened. What can cause this error? What files is inotify monitoring? Can it be fixed by un-monitoring files? Upping the limit on monitorable files does not seem like a great solution.

From the solution in the linked question: "Listen uses inotify by default on Linux to monitor directories for changes. It's not uncommon to encounter a system limit on the number of files you can monitor."

Comment: Are your Rails files in a folder that's mounted across a network? RubyMine gives me a similar warning when I edit files on the server via `sshfs`.

Answer (score -1):

the reason is because Routes functions use Listen and Listen on Linux system is limit on the number of files you can monitor in a directory.

When this limit is not enough to monitor all files inside a directory, the limit must be increased for Listen to work properly...

- For more information, check [inotify linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)
- if you want know, how work Listen, check this link [Listen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html)
- How solver the problem [Increasing the amount of inotify watchers](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)

Well, I will try to answer your question, this "Error" is not as such an Error, think the following, imagine that your car can run at a speed of 200 miles, but you have an automatic limit of 100 Miles per hour, what It will happen that when you reach that limit?, the car will show an alert on the panel, indicating that you exceeded the set speed limits. It's more or less what happens with this Listen scenario in Linux the use Routes On Rails

Hope to help